# swift: How can I override a public method in superclass to be a private method in subclass

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have a super class

```
class Father {
    public func doSomething() {
    } 
}
```

I want this child class to be

```
class Child: Father {
    private override func doSomething() {
    }
}
```

but Xcode says that

> Overriding instance method must be as accessible as the declaration it
>   overrides

so, how can I override a public method in superclass be a private method in subclass

THANK YOU

Answer (score 14):

You can't because that would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Essentially, any code that can operate on an instance of a superclass must also be able to operate on an instance of your subclass.

So, if some other class has a method

```
class Unrelated {
    func operateOnAThing(_ someThing:Father) {
        someThing.doSomething()
    }
}
```

then it still has to work when you do the following:

```
let aChild = Child()

unrelatedInstance.operateOnAThing(aChild)
```

If the `doSomething` method had more restrictive access in the `Child` class then you would get a runtime error.  To prevent this, you cannot make access more restrictive in a subclass.

Comment: thank you very much, I don't want anyone access doSomething() from Child while Father has the public method doSomething() ,  is there any way to make me happy ?

Comment: You could have two methods `doSomething` and a private method `reallyDoSomething`. In the superclass `doSomething` would call `reallyDoSomething`. In the subclass `doSomething` would throw an exception or something. The subclass can have whatever implementation of `reallyDoSomething` is appropriate

Comment: in fact I know this works but I don't want this , someone may call doSomething in Child ,  thank you very much again, it may be the only way.

Comment: Exactly; you see the problem. Someone *has* to be able to call `doSomething` on an instance of Child, because they probably won't even know that they are operating on an instance of Child as per my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by marking the public method as `unavailable` using the `@available` attribute. Then, call the method using `super` in the private method.

**Example:**

```
class Father {
    public func doSomething() {
        print("doSomething privatly")
    }
}

class Child: Father {
    @available (*, unavailable)
    override func doSomething() {
    }

    fileprivate func internal_doSomething() {
        super.doSomething()
    }
}

Child().internal_doSomething()
Child().doSomething() //'doSomething()' has been explicitly marked unavailable
```

**(Tested using Swift 4.0!)**

Comment: This will give a compiler error if you try and explicitly invoke the method on an instance of `Child` but it doesn't actually make the child method private - You can still call it if you access the `Child` instance via a variable of type `Father` - See https://gist.github.com/paulw11/d74a17780e4ceee57bf3d516a6e08313

Comment: @Paulw11 That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.